# Electron-Builder include external folder

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, electron-builder

I am building multiple electron apps and have one directory for common pictures and files. I would like to include them when building each app with electron-builder. The [docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) recommended -if I understood correctly- adding the path to the build > files key but it doesn't seem to work using this config file:

```
"build":{
    "files": [
        "**/*",
        "../common/img/*"
    ]
}
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
|git_folder
|-- electronapp1
|---- package.json
|-- electronapp2
|---- package.json
|-- common
|---- img
|---- js
|---- css
```

I am trying to access the common directories with i.e. this HTML code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../common/css/master.css">`. It works when starting it with `electron .` for debugging and developing, but when building with electron-builder, it doesn't seem to pack the common directories and throws "File not found" in the console.

Comment: "../common/img/*" missing double quote

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however in my code it's correct, was just the question where I missed it.

Comment: where is your builder configuration outside or inside `pakcage.json`?

Comment: Inside of package.json

Comment: which pakcage.json? both for electronapp 1, 2?

Comment: Yes and sadly don't get any error message.

Comment: "../common/**/*" try this then

Comment: Well would you like to say the app is not loading the image after build?

Comment: Tip: Open the devtools window after build

Comment: Still not loading the images even with the new setting! Says file not found.

Comment: Path is wrong. Let me see one <img> tag in your index.html

Comment: I did it this way: `<img src="../common/img/test.jpg">`

Comment: <img src= process.env.NODE_ENV ? "../common/img/test.jpg" : "./common/img/test.jpg">

Comment: and enable the nodeIntegration when you create BrowserWindow

Comment: After that I'll post full answer

Comment: @tpikachu Thanks for your extensive troubleshooting help. It doesn't work with those `src` parameters, now it doesn't even work in the development mode anymore (using `electron .`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration,

```
"extraResources": [
    {
        "from": "../common",
        "to": "common"
    }
],
"files": [
  "**/*"
],
```

So if I were you I'll configure it like this

```
const path = require("path");
const appPath = __dirname;
const appResourcePath = path.join(appPath, "..", "common")

module.exports = {
  appPath,
  appResourcePath
};
```

Then you can use this `appResourcePath` anywhere at your renderer
Such as

```
<img src=path.join(appResourcePath, 'img', 'background.png')>
```

Then this will be working in any environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly it doesn't work. The generated `src` tag `C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Programs\seitenapp\resources\app.asar\common\background.png` doesn't exist and `app.asar` is a file.

Comment: @creyD path.join(appResourcePath, 'img', 'background.png')

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work either. I think this has to do with the fact that app.asar is a file.

Comment: @creyD this asar is a electron content file which is accessible inside.

Comment: Asar is a simple extensive archive format, it works like tar that concatenates all files together without compression, while having random access support.

Comment: Will make pull request

Comment: Thank you very much. The actual repository is private, so I created a minimal example with just the needed files [here](https://github.com/creyD/electron_test).

Comment: @creyD you should include your common to inside your electron app

Comment: By using electron builder it's a bit impossible to including resources at non-src directory

Comment: I checked the asar after build but not including the common

Comment: but we can achieve this by using extra Resources

Comment: This will be working well and I created pull request to yours

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! Thanks for sticking around and actually showing me on github how to do this, you are the best!