# Electron builder works on development but not on install

Tags: electron, builder

I'm trying to follow other people who had a similar issue like this one
[Electron-Builder include external folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599298/electron-builder-include-external-folder) **I wish i could be more specific on what my problem is, the reason is that i dont know whats wrong.**

I am making a react app which has a server with an `sqlite db` and im trying to use `electron.js` to make it into an installable/executable

here is my dummy repo https://github.com/Juan321654/electron_react_with_build_installer_sqlite_db the `master branch` was just how to make electron work with react, the **`server branch` is the one that i need help with**
you can clone and just do `npm i`, `npm run start` to launch executable. `npm run build` to build

the code works fine in development mode and even after i make the build project with electron i can launch the executable and it works fine and it reads the data from the database, but as soon as i take the `dist` folder out of the project to send to someone or install the software, it stops working and it loads the app, but it does not read the data from the server/db, I am not sure if its missing `node modules` or the `server` folder, or maybe if im missing some kind of command in my `scripts` in the package.json?

Comment: does it already stop working when you move the dist folder to some other folder on your system outside of the project?  you say setup, so it is a nsis installer or which platform are you on? you can unpack the app.asar file to see if something is missing or seems off. you do not say what means "it stops working". no window appears? error dialog? window stays empty?

Comment: Hey, i mean that it doesnt read the data from the server, thank you for the suggestion ill update my question

Comment: try adding this to your electron-builder config: "asar": "false". I am not familiar with sqlite db, but if the database is part of the projectfiles, it will be packed into the app.asar archive, which may make it stop working. if it now suddenly works with asar false, you can remove asar false and instead try to exclude the sqlite db from the app.asar with the electron-builder option "external" or what ever it is called (I dont know the details because i never used that)

Comment: tried it but did not work, I did find something out, if I create a node server in the preload, it works fine i can try the main route with postman i get back the "hello world", but if i try to import a model from sequelize to do queries, it stays in a loading state until it times out after a while. so I'm trying to see if maybe preload doesn't support imports or something. Thank you again for the suggestion

Comment: preload doesnt support certain things depending on whether you set node integration and sandbox property of the window to false or true. Tipp: there is a electron discord, which can help with questions like that faster than stack overflow